# scheduleWithFixedRate does not work in grails project

Tags: grails, concurrency, cron, java-8

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;

class BootStrap {
    def init = { servletContext ->
      def sd =  Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
      sd.scheduleAtFixedRate(new CriticalTask(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   }
}
```

Known that `CriticalTask` class inherits from  `java.util.TimerTask` class.

The code inside run method of CriticalTask class works fine. However, the scheduling does not work.

*i don't know if it is an issue of web.xml configuration or another thing?*

This job is assumed to be launch for every minute.

---

#### Be informed also that i use  :

- java8
- grails 2.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a `ScheduledExecutorService`, you don’t need a `TimerTask`, in fact, using a `TimerTask` can be very counter-productive due to its confusing results. It works, because `TimerTask` implements `Runnable`, but all other methods besides `run()` have no meaning then.

I.e. `cancel()` and `scheduledExecutionTime()` work only if you use `TimerTask` together with the class [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

The method [`ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) returns a [`ScheduledFuture`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) which has methods like [`getDelay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Delayed.html#getDelay-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) and [`cancel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-) which you can use to control the task.

Comment: You have to decide. Either, you change your code to use the methods of the returned `ScheduledFuture` instead of the `TimerTask` or you change it to use `Timer` instead of `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`. I recommend the former, but I can’t make a suggestion for the new code as I don’t know your old code. You have only shown how you schedule the task (which doesn’t need a change), but not what you are going to do using the other methods.